# How to get many-many extra data using :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a typical model setup:

```
Store has_many Items
Orders has_many Items :through OrderItems
OrderItems
```

However, on the OrderItems I have a field called "quantity" to tell me how many of each item is on the order. I can't figure out how to properly retrieve this information.

```
ex. Order.find(1).order_items # has the list of items, but no "quantity" field
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same situation.I had used another association for this.Like

```
Store has_many Items
Orders has_many Items :through OrderItems
Orders has_many OrderItems
```

It will use the same order_id to map and then

```
Order.find(1).order_items # has the list of order_items, with "quantity" field in there
```

Comment: were you able to "join" the item and the order @item so that the "quantity" property would be on the @item?

Comment: well you can do the same in the item model like Items has_many OrderItems.Then Item.find(1).order_items will give you the list of quantity.I dont know,was this your question? or please clarify your question.

Comment: i realized you're right. i can do order_items.item and the item information is in there. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question: [Getting no method error when trying to read attribute from join model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789892/getting-no-method-error-when-trying-to-read-attribute-from-join-model)

The problem you are running into is that you are trying to grab the attribute order_items on a hash of Orders. Even though you are telling rails to only find(1), it still grabs a hash since it doesn't know there will only be one item grabbed when doing find(1). I believe if you do `Order.find(1).first.order_items.quantity` (not 100% sure that will work), that should work since you are telling rails there will only be one thing retrieved. Also, you can cycle through the retrieved orders by doing something like this:

```
  @orders = Order.find(1)
  @orders.each do |order|
    order.order_items.quantity
  end
```

however, if you are trying to get a 'count' of the order_items, you need to use .count instead of .quantity. Your question is a bit confusing.